# insertar scrollbar en treview ttkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola estoy intentando colocar un scrollbar a un treeview  pero no puedo poner una barra de dezplazamiento vertical, solo pude poner  estas pestañitas para navegar el treeview

```
import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import ttk

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title('HERRAMIENTA 1.0')
raiz.resizable(0, 1)
raiz.config(bg='silver', width='220', height='200')

# treeview
tree=ttk.Treeview(raiz )
tree.config(height=10)
tree.pack(side ='left')    

for  i in range(20):
    tree.insert('', tk.END, f'item{i}', text=f'item{i}')

for i in range(10):
    tree.insert('item0', tk.END, f'subitem{i}', text=f'subitems{i}' )

#skrolbar    
verscrlbar = ttk.Scrollbar(raiz, orient="vertical",  command=tree.yview)
verscrlbar.pack(side ='right', fill ='x')  
tree.configure(xscrollcommand = verscrlbar.set)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- Estás usando el atributo `xscrollcommand` del tree, cuando lo que enlazas es una barra vertical. Debe asignar a `yscrollcommand`.
- Debes forzar a la barra a ocupar todo el alto, no el ancho. Debe ser `fill ='y'`, no `fill ='x'`.
- Es siempre una muy buena idea usar un Frame que actúe de contenedor para la barra/barras y el Treeview. Ambas cosas deben ir siempre unidas y ocupar el mismo alto (o ancho si agregas una horizontal).

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title('HERRAMIENTA 1.0')
raiz.resizable(0, 1)
raiz.config(bg='silver', width='220', height='200')

tree_frame = tk.Frame(raiz)
tree_frame.config(height=10)
tree_frame.pack()

# treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame)
tree.pack(side='left')

for i in range(20):
    tree.insert('', tk.END, f'item{i}', text=f'item{i}')

for i in range(10):
    tree.insert('item0', tk.END, f'subitem{i}', text=f'subitems{i}')

# scrolbar
verscrlbar = ttk.Scrollbar(tree_frame, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
verscrlbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=verscrlbar.set)

raiz.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eVY9a3nTAyj73RAm9GSBiljxXKIDHHTk/view?usp=sharing] ¡Gracias por tu ayuda! @FJSevilla :).